# Why did my Git repository gain weight while deleting branches/tags?

Tags: git, gitlab

I work with Gitlab, and I proceeded to remove a large number of unused tags and branches on my current repository. The results of the cleanse is shown below:

```
 ________________ __________________ ______________ ______ 
|          |    # Branches    |    # Tags    |    Files   |
|=========================================================|
|  Before  |       506        |      925     |    576MB   |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  After   |       35         |      373     |   636.3MB  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem occurs with the **Files**. I didn't push any changes to `master`, and there is significantly less branches and tags on the repository. Despite that, the repository gained 60MB of unknown data.

Why is that ? I suspect it has to do with logs on operations on the repository, but that's pure guess. Is it normal ? If possible, how to get rid of those "unwanted, mysterious" files ?

Comment: You can run the garbage collection using `git gc`, or wait until GitLab does it (every 14 days or so).

Comment: How are you measuring this usage?

Comment: @torek Gitlab shows you on the main screen of your repository those metrics. (If the question was for me)

Comment: It was. That's weird, because deleting tag and branch names is normally very low-cost. There might be some GitLab settings for this—it's possible they have things set up to *not* run a full `git gc` and instead to explode pack files to loose objects (which would be odd but not impossible). Or, perhaps they update stats asynchronously and they managed to do it in the middle of a gc, before the loose objects got removed.

Comment: If it's a timing artifact, the space usage will go back down again the next time you do something that updates the space-usage-calculation. But since I don't use GitLab I can't really say.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove files in git, git does not actually delete them instantely. This is so that if you accidentally delete something wiht force you can still get ich back using `git recover`. If you really need your files completely removed you can manually start gits garbage collection via `git gc --auto`
'

Note: `git gc` gets periodically called automatically. However it will only acutally remove your garbage if you have ~7000 loose objects or 50 packfiles (unless you played around with your configuration to change these values). So depending on how much you removed, manually calling it might be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, however, are tags and branches counted as files ? I could get the gist of it if I added files and/or content to my repository, but I only **removed** things, being considered as files or not. If there an explaination ?

Comment: Well you branches contain files, right? What happens here is probably git copying your files and tags somewhere to make a recovery possible. I do not know however what exactly gets copied where and would need to look deeper into this

Comment: That was a guess indeed, that the system keeps a copy of each deleted file and/or tag in whatever file format somewhere, and maybe the metadata/side informations about it makes it actually bigger. Thank you for your insight !